# Imply that if $x$ is a real number satisfies $x^2 = x$, then $x =0$ or $x=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

I am trying to use the algebraic properties of Real Numbers to try and prove this but dont know how to complete the proof. I think the important properties are that $a\cdot 0 = 0$ and that $a\cdot 1 = a $, but I dont know how to disprove any other scenario. I tried doing $c^2 = c$ and then $c = \sqrt2$ but this doesn't get me anywhere. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $c^2=c\implies c(c-1)=0\implies c=0$ or $c=1$

Comment: The $x$ may be complex.  Same result.

Answer (score 1):

If $x^2=x $, you can write it as $x^2-x=0$ or $x (x-1)=0$. Since the product of two non-zero numbers is never  $0$ in $\mathbb R $, either  $x=0$ or $x-1=0$. That is, either $x=0$ or $x=1$.

Comment: I see, I can't believe I didn't think to subtract to make it = 0. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Because $\mathbb{R}$ is a field every real number $a\ne 0$ has an inverse $a^{-1}$ so that $a\cdot a^{-1}=1$. The equation $x^2=x$ has the $x=0$ solution, but supposing $x\ne 0$ we can multiply both sides for $x^{-1}$ obtaining $x=1$

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: If $x \ne 0$ then you can divide both sides by $x$ to obtain $x = 1$.

Case 2: If $x = 0$ then the equality holds as well.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x^2 = x \implies x^2 - x = 0 \implies x(x-1)=0
$$

Since we have $a\cdot 0 =0$ $\forall a\in \mathbb{R}$, we need $x=0$ or $(x-1)=0$

Therefore: $x\in \{0,1\}$